# Not Serializable exception when integrating Spark SQL and Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

This is my source code where in Im getting some data from the server side, which keeps on generating a stream of data. And then for each RDD , I'm applying the SQL Schema, and once this table is created Im trying to select something from this DStream.

```
    List<String> males = new ArrayList<String>();
    JavaDStream<String> data = streamingContext.socketTextStream("localhost", (port));
    data.print();
    System.out.println("Socket connection established to read data from Subscriber Server");
    JavaDStream<SubscriberData> streamData = data
            .map(new Function<String, SubscriberData>() {
                public SubscriberData call(String record) {
                    String[] stringArray = record.split(",");
                    SubscriberData subscriberData = new SubscriberData();
                    subscriberData.setMsisdn(stringArray[0]);
                    subscriberData.setSubscriptionType(stringArray[1]);

                    subscriberData.setName(stringArray[2]);
                    subscriberData.setGender(stringArray[3]);
                    subscriberData.setProfession(stringArray[4]);
                    subscriberData.setMaritalStatus(stringArray[5]);


                    return subscriberData;

                }

            });

    streamData.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<SubscriberData>,Void>(){
        public Void call(JavaRDD<SubscriberData> rdd){

    JavaSQLContext sqlContext = new JavaSQLContext(sc);
    JavaSchemaRDD subscriberSchema = sqlContext.applySchema(rdd,SubscriberData.class);

    subscriberSchema.registerAsTable("SUBSCRIBER_DIMENSION");
    System.out.println("all data");
    JavaSchemaRDD names = sqlContext.sql("SELECT msisdn FROM SUBSCRIBER_DIMENSION WHERE GENDER='Male'");
    System.out.println("afterwards");

    List<String> males = new ArrayList<String>();

     males = names.map(new Function<Row, String>() {
        public String call(Row row) {
            return row.getString(0);
        }
    }).collect();
    System.out.println("before for");
    for (String name : males) {
        System.out.println(name);
            }
    return null;
    }
    });
streamingContext.start();
```

But it throws this Serializable Exception althought the classes Im using do implement Serialization.

```
    14/11/06 12:55:20 ERROR scheduler.JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1415258720000 ms.1
 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1242)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSchemaRDD.map(JavaSchemaRDD.scala:42)
at com.hp.tbda.rta.SubscriberClient$2.call(SubscriberClient.java:206)
at com.hp.tbda.rta.SubscriberClient$2.call(SubscriberClient.java:1)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:274)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:274)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:527)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:527)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
... 20 more
```

Comment: just a side note: Scala is much more concise and readable to work with Spark. Worth the learning effort.

Comment: Indeed, Scala is simpler than Java in terms of Spark coding standards. But the requirement needs to be fulfilled in Java. Thanks!

Comment: I have similar spark streaming application but my application crashes after 2 hours have you faced similar problem. Thanks @Navin Ahmed

Comment: No bro. Haven't faced that kind of an issue as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SparkContext` is not serializable as it's only usable on the driver and should NOT be included in any closure. I'm afraid that support for SQL on Spark Streaming is only at research level at the moment. See [this presentation from the Spark Summit](http://spark-summit.org/2014/talk/streamsql-on-spark-manipulating-streams-by-sql-using-spark) for the details.

To create the intended RDD of ids of male subscribers you can use map and filter:

```
maleSubscribers = subscribers.filter(subsc => subcs.getGender == "Male")
                             .map(subsc => subsc.getMsisdn)
```

Comment: I was able to apply SQL on Streaming data. We are not supposed to have the declaration of JavaSQLContext within the foreachRDD. Had to do that outside the for loop. Thanks for the help though. Appreciate it